# Will "select for share" take no effective without transaction?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6

To understand "select for share", I just read https://shiroyasha.io/selecting-for-share-and-update-in-postgresql.html.

I just want to confirm that, if I do "select for share" without a transaction, like:

```sql
select * from table_a where id = 1 for share
```

As the transaction has only this single "select" statement, though "for share" acquires a lock, but the lock will be released immediately, thus it roughly equals to "no lock", right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is true that the lock won't be held any longer than the statement executes, so it is pretty useless. Still, `SELECT ... FOR SHARE` will modify the locked row just like any other row lock, thus causing a write and blocking all concurrent modifications, and the statement will acquire a transaction ID.

So you are paying the price for a row lock without any benefit.

Comment: In the case of `SELECT ... FOR SHARE`, the transaction will end once `SELECT` returns, right? In turn, once `SELECT` returns, the lock will be released. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Sorry, I somehow missed that it is a single-statement transaction. I have fixed the answer.

Comment: Thank you much very for the answer. Would you please look at the other related question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74698598/what-happens-for-for-share-with-nested-select?