# What happens for "FOR SHARE" with nested select?

Tags: postgresql, locking, postgresql-9.6

Say, I have a nested select:

```sql
WITH candidate AS (
   select * table_a where flag = 'a'
)
select * from candidate where other_flag = 'b' for share
```

This SQL indirectly `select` from `table_a` with `for share`. In this case, will row locks be acquired on returned rows from `table_a`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That query should not acquire any row locks, because `candidate` is not a base table. But you can see yourself: run

```
EXPLAIN WITH (...) SELECT ...
```

and see if there is a `LockRows` node in the execution plan.

If you want to lock the rows, you will have to use `FOR SHARE` in the subquery.

Comment: What happens if the CTE is "flattened" in a current Postgres version? (I know this won't happen in 9.6)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name It also won't lock the rows, I checked with `EXPLAIN`. I think it would be a bug if locking depended on whether the CTE was inlined or not.